# Invoking AWS Lambda Authorizer using Function URL

Tags: aws-lambda, lambda-authorizer

I have implemented an AWS Lambda Authorizer in Java (type=REQUEST). I would like to invoke the lambda using a [Function URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-urls.html). I need to pass the following fields to my Lambda `AuthorizerEvent`:

- headers
- type (REQUEST)
- methodArn

I am sending the HTTP GET message using Postman. The headers get mapped correctly to the event object. However, `type` and `methodARN` are shown as `null` in the CloudWatch logs and the Function URL returns a `502 Bad Gateway` error:

> Received AuthorizerEvent(type=null, authorizationToken=null, headers={...}, methodArn=null)

I've tried putting `type` and `methodArn` in query parameters, headers and body (even though REQUEST authorizers don't use the body, see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-lambda-authorizer-input.html)). I also can't find complete documentation outlining how HTTP parameters are mapped to the lambda request event parameters for Authorizer Function URLs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you figure a way to invoke authorizer with lambda function URLs?

Comment: @systemdebt unfortunately no, I never figured this out. I ended up using [Serverless Framework](https://www.serverless.com/), which made it easier to invoke local or remote lambdas using the CLI.